# Bootstrap in Angular 5: How to have selected tab active when coming back to the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular5

I am using bootstrap nav-pills in my Angular 2 application. I want to show the user selected tab as active tab when user comes back to this page from another component. So user goes from this component to other and then comes back here, which is when I want the user to see the same tab that he selected.    If I use [ngClass] to set active tab, the tabs don't work properly - pills work, but tab content does not change.
Code:
    `<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li [ngClass]="{'active': 'p' == activeTab }" (click)="activeTab = 'p';"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#personal"><span class="fa fa-user fa-icon-right-margin-small"></span> Personal</a></li>
            <li [ngClass]="{'active': 'g' == activeTab }" (click)="activeTab = 'g';"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#group"><span class="fa fa-users fa-icon-right-margin-small"></span> Group</a></li>
        </ul>` 
Also, when user comes back to this page, the first one that is, Personal 
 tab content keeps showing as active.  I saw some js solutions where active tab was stored in local storage. Can I get a non-js answer? Thanks. Bootstrap version - 3.3.7, Angular - 5
Also, I tried to manually trigger the click() event of the tab by setting ids of li elements using # in html as `<li #g ...` and `this.g.nativeElement.click(); // if active tab = 'g', g = group` in my component.ts, but after that when page rendered, It showed first tab, that is "personal" only as selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Angular RouterModule then you can use the routerLink and routerLinkActive attributes. This allows you to simply and automatically specify a named class to add to whichever routerLink is currently active.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="personal" routerLinkActive="active">
            <span class="fa fa-user fa-icon-right-margin-small"></span> Personal
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="group" routerLinkActive="active">
            <span class="fa fa-users fa-icon-right-margin-small"></span> Group
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to keep the functional elements of your code unchanged. Hope this helps.